# Organizing partials for a polymorphic resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, organization

I'm looking for how others typically organize their partials for a polymorphic resource.

Example:

I have `Image` which is polymorphic and depending on what is `imageable`, I want to display things slightly different.

I have a partial `images/_image` and can call `render imageable.images`. My current mindset is to have my image partial check what type `imageable` is and then have another partial, specific to that case. My organization would be something along the lines of:

```
images/
  _image.html.haml
  _product.html.haml
  _post.html.haml
  _user.html.haml
```

My `_image` partial would look something like:

```
%div
  = render :partial => "images/#{imageable.type}"
```

Does this seem like a bad approach, or flat out the wrong approach? I think it would be much nicer to just call `render imageable.images` from anywhere than having to call `render :partial => ...` all over the place.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. How have you done it?

EDIT: A long time has gone by and I'm still wondering if anyone has any input on this. Throwing up a bounty to see if that draws some attention.

Answer (score 2):

In your code now it's unclear that `_product` actually is an `_image`.

I think the intention in Rails is to do it like this:

```
shared/
    _image.html.haml
    imageable/
      _product.html.haml
      _post.html.haml
      _user.html.haml
```

Then in the `_image` partial you call:

`render :partial => imageable/#{image.type}", :image => image`

Now it is clear from your directory structure what your polymorphism is.

(note: I used the `shared` directory, but ofcourse when your image partial isn't actually shared between views it should be in some view directory like if you actually have an `images_controller` the directory should be called `images`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got the right approach, but i think the final step for cleanliness is to eliminate the images partial that selects another partial by instead passign that behavior to a helper. something like...

```
module ImagesHelper
  def show_image(imageable)
    render :partial => "images/#{imageable.class.to_s.tableize}"
  end  
end
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit under the weather so I can't test it. But you should just put in `<%= render imageable.images %>` and see what it says. It should work because it should be using .modelname or .class :) If it doesn't work I would do what you're doing as mentioned above. If it doesn't work though, please comment with what it says, because then I'll probably make a patch to the rails core for that, really should work as such.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for the response. Arguably, I should tag my question with subjective (which might make my bounty a little awkward). But, yes, as you have pointed out, it definitely DOES work. My question is more subjective in the sense of how people handle these things. The way I organize these files always seems "dirty" to me and was looking for a little more insight into how other people do it. Cheers.

Comment: I would do it `<%= render resource %>` it's cleaner imo. While I might not know that it's going to be a polymorphic partial right of the bat, it's not that hard to find out since they're all in there and worse case scenario just add a comment above the line or something :)

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your original idea is on the right track, with a minor adjustment:

```
= render imageable.images

# images/_image.html.haml
= render image.imageable_type.underscore, :object => image.imageable, :image => image

# images/_product.html.haml
// Custom code for product image (with product and image local variables)
```